# how to change validation styles of textbox

Tags: wpf, material-design

I use `MaterialDesign` style in project.

I want to change validation textbox style.

I use this style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0" />
    <Style.Triggers>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Validation.HasError}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

but do't change style.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your binding is invalid. This works:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Test, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Margin="10">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, i use this but do't apply style

Comment: @ar.gorgin: What is not being applied...?

Comment: @ar.gorgin: Of course the style that you set to Style property to is being applied.